# How to replace the id of checkbox at YII?

Tags: yii

Code of my view

```
    <?php 
$temp = CHtml::listData($roles,'name','name');
                echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'role', $temp,
                           array('labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;'), // add this code
                     ));
            ?>
```

array $temp output is

```
array(7) { ["Administrator"]=> string(13) "Administrator" ["Creator"]=> string(7) "Creator" ["Director"]=> string(8) "Director" ["Implementer"]=> string(11) "Implementer" ["Reviewer"]=> string(8) "Reviewer" ["Superadmin"]=> string(10) "Superadmin" ["Temporary Director"]=> string(18) "Temporary Director" }
```

at HTML output is

```
<span id="User_role"><input id="User_role_0" value="Administrator" type="checkbox" name="User[role][]"> <label style="display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;" for="User_role_0">Administrator</label><br>
<input id="User_role_1" value="Creator" type="checkbox" name="User[role][]"> <label style="display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;" for="User_role_1">Creator</label><br>
<input id="User_role_2" value="Director" type="checkbox" name="User[role][]"> <label style="display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;" for="User_role_2">Director</label><br>
<input id="User_role_3" value="Implementer" type="checkbox" name="User[role][]"> <label style="display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;" for="User_role_3">Implementer</label><br>
<input id="User_role_4" value="Reviewer" type="checkbox" name="User[role][]"> <label style="display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;" for="User_role_4">Reviewer</label><br>
<input id="User_role_5" value="Superadmin" type="checkbox" name="User[role][]"> <label style="display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;" for="User_role_5">Superadmin</label><br>
<input id="User_role_6" value="Temporary Director" type="checkbox" name="User[role][]"> <label style="display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;" for="User_role_6">Temporary Director</label></span>
```

What I want is

```
<input id="User_role_Administrator" value="Administrator" type="checkbox" name="User[role][]">
```

How Should I do

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the `id` attribute of checkboxes in a `checkBoxList`. It would be invalid HTML anyway because you would assign the same `id` to more than one element on the DOM.

I assume that you need the `id` to address the inputs from javascript. You could assign a `class` instead:

```
<?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'role', $temp, array(
    'labelOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;'
    ),
    'class' => 'user-role',
));  ?>
```

Then in `jQuery` you get all inputs with `$('.user-role')`.

Comment: Actually, I want to pick up the Identify id/class. bec I wanna use the DOM to do something by jquery. How could I assign by id/class?

Answer (score 0):

This is checkbox list.

```
<?php 
                echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'role', $arr_roles,
                    array('labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle;'),
                            'class'=>'user-role',));
            ?>
```

This is javascript

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('temp-director', "     
     $('input.user-role').click(function(){ 
        if( $(this).val() == 'Temporary Director'){     
            $('#extra').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
        }
    });
");
?>
```